# How to set an iframe's src to the same page (with a different anchor)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a demo page. In that page is a textbox and an iframe. When the value in the textbox changes, the iframe should be updated to a new url based on that value (in reality, the textbox is hidden, and is changing based on a more complicated lookup, but that's irrelevant to this question). The code for that should be pretty straight-forward:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".id-textbox").change(function(){
    var entryId=$(".id-textbox").val();
    var srcTxt='http://[site]/#id=' + entryId;
    var iframe = $('.webaccess-iframe iframe');
    iframe.attr('src',srcTxt);
  });
});
```

The issue is the url, and the fact that it looks like:
    `http://[site]/#id={some id}`
If you visit that page, specifying an id, it will actually open up the page to the document with the id you specified - I have no control over that, that's how you use that site, which I didn't write.

If you type a valid id into the textbox the first time, the src of the iframe is set, the page loads correctly, and everything is great. If you then type a different valid id in, though, the src of the iframe is set to the new url, and then nothing happens, because the browser (at least in Firefox) still thinks it's pointing to the same url. After all, it technically *is* the same url - it's not the browser's fault the site we're trying to visit uses anchors that way.

I tried giving it the url and then refreshing the iframe (with contentDocument.location.reload()), but that didn't seem to change the behavior. I also tried giving it about:blank and then the url. That worked exactly half the time: as you type valid ids, it loads your page, then it loads about:blank instead of the next page, then it loads a page correctly, then it loads about:blank instead, etc.

Is there any way to force the iframe to actually load the new url?

Comment: Can you try `var srcTxt='http://[site]/#' + entryId;`? Note how `#smth` don't have the same syntax as GET requests `?id=smth`. If it doesn't work, you can also try `var srcTxt='#' + entryId;`.

Comment: Is it really a new url? Does the server actually read the hash and output something different based on it? I thought the hash was only visible client-side.

Comment: There shouldn't be any harm in adding a meaningless querystring to the URL; that will make the iFrame think it's new and reload it.  For example, something like `var srcTxt='http://[site]/?myCrazyQuerystring=' + new Date().getTime() + '#id=' + entryId;`.  The server should ignore the querystring since it's not expecting it.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, it is really a new url. The server does actually output a different page based on the id using that format for its urls.

Comment: @JacobM While silly, that totally worked. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: I kinda doubt the server is returning different html, it's more likely that the client on dom ready is reading the hash and then ajax loading in more content (or simply showing it).

Comment: OK, I posted my (somewhat hacky) "solution" as an answer.  Glad it helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a somewhat hacky workaround, an iFrame will regard a change to a querystring as a new URL -- but most servers will ignore querystrings they aren't expecting.  So as a fix, you can add a meaningless querystring that will change every time (say a datestamp).

For example:

```
var srcTxt='http://[site]/?myCrazyQuerystring=' + new Date().getTime() + '#id=' + entryId;
```

Comment: Note for potential future readers: while I agree that it is kinda hacky, this was also easy to implement, and 100% worked to fix the particular issue. Not necessarily the right kind of clever, but clever nonetheless. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This behavior seems to be specific to Firefox. A bug, maybe ?

Note that if the page in the iframe is on the same domain as the container page, you can do (pure JavaScript)

```
iframe.contentDocument.location.replace(srcTxt);
```

This won't work if the iframe is pointing to a page on a different domain, as `contentDocument` won't be readable by JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://[site]/#{some id}
```

without `id=`

Comment: I'm not sure what you think that would accomplish - that isn't the same at all...

Comment: If you are using `#id=something` in the URL, then it means that you must have IDs like `id="id=something"` on the website. It's true that it isn't the same, but it looks like this can be your problem.